# Show a cell progress using papermill and tqdm

Tags: jupyter-notebook, tqdm, papermill

I have a notebook with just 2 or 3 cells, but one of those cells takes about 10 minutes. That cell runs a loop that uses `tqdm`, so If I run the notebook I can get the progress. Nevertheless, when I use `papermill.execute_notebook`, obviously I can't see that widget.

How can I display the current progress of that cell?